# How to change the drop shadow (or shade) from a ModalBottomSheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

A ModalBottomSheet automatically renders a shade or shadow over the underling Screen.

Setting background color to transparant in the [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) method only effects the area holding the child widget.
It does not remove the drop shadow under the modal.

Can I remove or change the opacity of the shadow?

Comment: Try setting  _elevation_ parameter to 0

Comment: You can try to override the [bottom sheet theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheetThemeData-class.html) in your theme data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
...
```

Note that I am using the property 'barrierColor'

Comment: Edit: added the line that pointed out the property 'barrierColor'

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increase or decrease the shadow u can change the `elevation:`

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    elevation: 2.0,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
```

0 means no shadow, Use multiples of 2.0